# How to match in a single/common Regex Group matching or based on a condition

Tags: regex, go, regex-group

I would like to extract two different test strings `/i/int/2021/11/18/019e1691-614c-4402-a8c1-d0239ad1ac45/,640-1_999899,480-1_999899,960-1_999899,1280-1_999899,1920-1_999899,.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8?set-segment-duration=responsive`
and

`/i/int/2021/11/25/,live_20211125_215206_sendeton_640x360-50p-1200kbit,live_20211125_215206_sendeton_480x270-50p-700kbit,live_20211125_215206_sendeton_960x540-50p-1600kbit,live_20211125_215206_sendeton_1280x720-50p-3200kbit,live_20211125_215206_sendeton_1920x1080-50p-5000kbit,.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8`

with a single RegEx and in Group-1.

By using this RegEx `^.[i,na,fm,d]+\/(.+([,\/])?(\/|.+=.+,\/).+\/[,](live.([^,]).).+_)?.+(640).*$` I can get the second string to match the desired result **`int/2021/11/25/,live_20211125_215206_`**

but the first string does not match in Group-1 and the missing expected test string 1 extraction is **`int/2021/11/18/019e1691-614c-4402-a8c1-d0239ad1ac45`**

Any pointers on this is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want both values in group 1, you can use:

```
^/(?:[id]|na|fm)/([^/\s]*/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/\S*?)(?:/,|[^_]+_)640(?:\D|$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `/` Match literally
- `(?:[id]|na|fm)` Match one of `i` `d` `na` `fm`
- `/` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^/\s]*/` Match any char except a `/` or a whitespace char, then match `/`
  - `\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/` Match a date like pattern
  - `\S*?` Match optional non whitespace chars, as few as possible
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?:/,|[^_]+_)` Match either `/,` or 1+ chars other than `_` and then match `_`
- `640` Match literally
- `(?:\D|$)` Match either a non digits or assert end of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H36pBM/1) and a [go demo](https://ideone.com/0ETtgX).

Answer (score 0):

We can't know all the rules of how the strings your are matching are constructed, but for just these two example strings provided:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)(\/i/int/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/.*)(?:\/,|_[\w_]+)640`)
    var str = `
/i/int/2021/11/18/019e1691-614c-4402-a8c1-d0239ad1ac45/,640-1_999899,480-1_999899,960-1_999899,1280-1_999899,1920-1_999899,.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8?set-segment-duration=responsive
/i/int/2021/11/25/,live_20211125_215206_sendeton_640x360-50p-1200kbit,live_20211125_215206_sendeton_480x270-50p-700kbit,live_20211125_215206_sendeton_960x540-50p-1600kbit,live_20211125_215206_sendeton_1280x720-50p-3200kbit,live_20211125_215206_sendeton_1920x1080-50p-5000kbit,.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8`

    match := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(str, -1)

    for _, val := range match {
        fmt.Println(val[1])
    }
}
```